# Параметр для RelativeLayout

Tags: android

После создания `RelativeLayout` установил на параметры `layout_width` и
`layout_height` значение `match_parent`, но система пишет что для `layout_height` нужно использовать `wrap_content`, а не `match_parent`.

С чем это может быть связано и не будет ли критичным использование `match_parent` в обоих параметрах `RelativeLayout`?

Comment: У потомка, поди, `layout_alignParentBottom` установлен?

Comment: Разметку хоть покажите...

Comment: <ScrollView 
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
   >
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">                           <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

Answer (score 4):

Система ругается потому что у вас в разметке присутствует ScrollView и использование match_parent делает его бессмысленным - содержимое просто будет расти под размер экрана и не будет скролиться.

Comment: На самом деле скроллится при обоих значениях 'layout_weight'. Похоже замечание системы носит рекомендательный характер. Рекомендованное значение логичнее.

Comment: А вы на всех платформах и версиях андроид проверяли? Не факт, что будет везде работать...

Comment: Придется с вами согласиться. Конечно, не на всех.